# MongoDB $graphLookup for missing/null connectToField

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following collection:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "A",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "B",
    "parentId": "A"
  }
]
```

And the following query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: null,
      connectFromField: "id",
      connectToField: "parentId",
      as: "children",
      depthField: "depth"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$children"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        id: "$children.id",
        depth: "$children.depth"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

MongoDB returns the desired result:

```json
[
  {
    "depth": 0,
    "id": "A"
  },
  {
    "depth": 1,
    "id": "B"
  }
]
```

However, when the original collection doesn't have the `parentId` fields, the MongoDB doesn't match such documents against `null` check and returns empty result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "B",
    "parentId": "A"
  }
]
```

Here's the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0mRD87MiwS2).

Is there a way to match `parentId` when it's both set to `null` and doesn't exist?

Comment: I think the `startWith` param should be filled with `$id`, as it should be the *connectFromField with which to start the recursive search* from [the official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) and you can see how it goes in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nUqKOQfA9Ou). I think your case of using null in the `startWith` field may not have a well-defined meaning. It looks to me that it is trying to do some unconditional lookup or not looking up anything at all.

Comment: `startWith` is just an initialization value for the `connectToField` to start recursive matching with and I don't think that this is invalid use case. The only problem is that `connectToField` doesn't match document with `null` when the field is missing and I'm looking for away to actually match them, maybe with some expression?

Comment: It should be `connectFromField` instead of `connectToField`? For your case of parent-to-children lookup, if connectToField contains a null value, that indicates the document has no (meaningful) parent. I am not sure if it should return anything...?

Comment: Nevertheless, if non-existent field is a concern to you, you can consider doing a one-time sanitization like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9--w8cYeNC-) so you can perform your `$graphLookup` correctly.

Comment: Yep, I can add null values to the collection of course, but the main goal of this question was to avoid that :)

Comment: `null` and `missing` are different types that won't match in aggregation expressions